# Issue with template template parameter in function template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to use a template template parameter and my code will not complile.

```
template<class DataType, template<class T> class Container>
void foo(Container<DataType> test)
{
    
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> testVec{1,2,3,4};
    
    foo<int, std::vector>(testVec);
}
```

The error message is
"No matching function for call to 'foo'.

1. Candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'Container'"

Can someone help me out?

Comment: please include the complete error message in the question. My compiler tells me what is wrong https://godbolt.org/z/96a3Eq. If you don't understand the error message, others will, in any case the error message is what you should use to fix the error

Comment: @idclev463035818 Adding error message is a must, but to be fair, GCC is being surprisingly unhelpful here, with the classical `note: template argument deduction/substitution failed`.

Comment: I have added the error message. Thanks both

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the proposed candidate often helps me a lot. For some reasons askers often skip all the additional information and focus on a "it doesn't work" version of the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion: try with

```
// ...............................VVVVVVVVV
template<class DataType, template<class ...> class Container>
void foo(Container<DataType> test)
{
    
}
```

The problem is that `std::vector` accept **two** type template parameters; the second one with a default value.

If you write

```
// ...............................VVVVVVV
template<class DataType, template<class T> class Container>
```

you ask for a template-template parameter that accept a single type template parameter.

So you can solve asking **two** type template parameters

```
// ...............................VVVVVVVVVVVV
template<class DataType, template<class, class> class Container>
```

or, to be more flexible, a variadic list of type template parameters

```
// ...............................VVVVVVVVV
template<class DataType, template<class ...> class Container>
```

As pointed by HolyBlackCat (thanks) your code (so a template-template parameter asking for a single type template parameter) should fail before C++17 but should be accepted starting from C++17 (the matching rules are changed).

Unfortunately this works with g++ but not for clang++: the clang++ developer doesn't implement, by default, this new C++17 matching rule.

But HolyBlackCat report that also clang++ accept your code adding a special parameter: `-frelaxed-template-template-args`.

Comment: Or OP can add `-std=c++17`, then the code should work as is.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Are you sure? I mean... I know that C++17 changed something about template-template matching (and, unfortunately, I never remember exactly what) but I see that g++ (compiling C++17) accept the code where clang++ (also a recent version, also compiling C++20) gives an error.

Comment: IIIRC Clang developers refused to implement this change because they deemed the new wording defective, because it breaks some old code for no good reason. Clang accepts it if you pass `-frelaxed-template-template-args`.

Comment: interesting that this does not require `std::vector` to be a variadic template. Now I wonder if it is possible to have a template template parameter that only matches variadic templates

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Interesting. I didn't know it (or I didn't remember it). Added to the answer: thanks!

Comment: @idclev463035818 - Good question. No, I suppose there is no way...  but I'm not sure.

Comment: @max66 I think I am going to ask a question, just needs some time to prepare a good case