# How to match only variadic templates with a template template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-templates

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <template<class...> class C>
struct foo {
    foo() { std::cout << "base case\n";}
};

template <template<class> class C>
struct foo< C > {
    foo() { std::cout << "single param case\n";}
};

template <template<class,class> class C>
struct foo< C > {
    foo() { std::cout << "two param case\n";}
};

template <typename T> struct bar1 {};
template <typename T,typename U> struct bar2 {};
template <typename T,typename U,typename V> struct bar3 {};
template <typename...T> struct barN {};

int main() {
    foo<bar1> f;
    foo<bar2> g;
    foo<bar3> h;
    foo<barN> n;
}
```

Output is ([gcc10.2@godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jP4P4o)):

```
single param case
two param case
base case
base case
```

Suppose `barX` is given and that I have other templates with varying number of type parameters. Some variadic some not.

Is it possible to write a specialization that only matches the variadic template (`barN` in the above example)?

Comment: What would be the use of such a specialization?

Comment: @JeffGarrett does it have to be useful? Its a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64737968/4117728) (but I don't think it adds much context). Consider some machinery that instantiats templates for different combinations of template parameters, then you want to know the arity. A testing framework for templates is what comes to my mind, but I really don't have a concrete case at hand.

Comment: @JeffGarrett or much simpler. Given a template `T` write a trait that unambiuously determines if `T` is a variadic template. One can simply try to instantiate it with different number of parameters, but the possibility of defaults makes it difficult to be certain about variadicness

Comment: Neither clang or gcc compiles this with c++17.

Comment: @Kostas do you know why? I would have to do some research, perhaps open another question. However, the example `foo` isn't essential for the question, as anyhow I am asking for something to replace `foo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can determine whether a class template that can be instantiated with 0 template arguments is genuinely variadic or (merely) has defaults for all its non-variadic template arguments, by counting the arguments to an 0-argument instantiation:

```
template<class> constexpr unsigned argc_v;
template<template<class...> class C, class... A> constexpr unsigned argc_v<C<A...>> = sizeof...(A);
template<template<class...> class, class = void> constexpr bool is_variadic_v = false;
template<template<class...> class C> constexpr bool is_variadic_v<C, std::void_t<C<>>> = argc_v<C<>> == 0;
```

Then we can use this to build a set of specializations that respectively accept only variadic, 1-argument (with possible default) and 2-argument (with possible default/s) class templates:

```
template<template<class...> class, class = std::true_type>
struct foo;

template<template<class...> class C>
struct foo<C, std::bool_constant<is_variadic_v<C>>> {
    foo() { std::cout << "variable case\n"; }
};

template<template<class> class C>
struct foo<C, std::bool_constant<!is_variadic_v<C> && argc_v<C<void>> == 1>> {
    foo() { std::cout << "single param case\n";}
};

template<template<class, class> class C>
struct foo<C, std::bool_constant<!is_variadic_v<C> && argc_v<C<void, void>> == 2>> {
    foo() { std::cout << "two param case\n";}
};
```

I'm a bit disappointed that the latter `argc_v` tests are necessary (in C++20 mode); I think it's [something to do with P0522 / CWG150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47293162/how-is-p0522r0-breaking-code).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xzMKz4).

Comment: This is awesome. It was a rather academical question. I had hit a wall and was afraid that I have reconsdier my whole mental image of variadic templates. Now I am curious, did you actually use something like this for something?

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't believe so; it took some thinking about the visible differences between a 0-argument variadic and default-argument class template instantiation to come up with. That said, I am familiar with the quirks of decomposing class template instantiations, but mostly from the angle of determining which class template they are an instantiation of.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question. Unfortunately the answer is No.
There is no general way to determine if a template had a template parameter pack or just a bunch of regular template parameters with or without defaults.

The reason is that non-variadic templates can bind to variadic template template parameters and the concrete types of a template can bind to a template parameter pack.

So effectively the information is not available via deduction/specialization. And in general this is good - without this feature variadic templates would lose much of their power.

But if we could limit the maximum length of template arguments we could write a trait with a bunch of template specializations. This works because of partial ordering (as you have shown in your question): [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/o85f5o)