# C++20 concepts: Check for presence of a variadic member function template (or best-practices alternative)

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Is it possible to have a concept check for the presence of variadic member function templates, or for the presence of member function templates in general?

Background:

I have a set of classes and class templates that model math functions that can be evaluated for value vectors of arbitrary length. That is to say, given such a function `f`, you could write

```c++
double y  = f(1.0, 2, 4.2);
double y2 = f(mathy_vector<3>{1.0, 2, 4.2});
```

along with a few other operations such as mathematical derivation that are really the whole point of the thing but irrelevant to this particular question. These functions are composable, e.g. you can have a `sum<product<constant, variable<0>>, variable<1>>` for `2 * x + y`.

I would like to have a concept that matches this function interface to constrain the composable class templates along the lines of

```c++
template<mathy_function left_hand_side,
         mathy_function right_hand_side>
class sum { ... };
```

SSCCE:

What I got to work is this:

```c++
#include <concepts>

template<int N>
struct mathy_vector { };

///////////////////
// Broken bit here
///////////////////

template<typename T>
concept mathy_function = requires(T f) {
  // I would really like to test for a variadic op() here.
  { f(0.0) } -> std::same_as<double>;
  { f(1, 2, 3) } -> std::same_as<double>;

  // I would also like to check for arbitrary N here
  { f(mathy_vector<100>{}) } -> std::same_as<double>;
};

///////////////////
// end of broken bit
///////////////////

struct dummy_function {
  double operator()(std::convertible_to<double> auto&&...) const {
    return 0.0;
  }

  template<int N>
  double operator()(mathy_vector<N> const &v) const {
    return 0.0;
  }
};

template<mathy_function F>
void do_stuff(F const &f) { }

template<mathy_function LHS, mathy_function RHS>
struct sum { };

int main() {
  dummy_function f;
  do_stuff(f);
  sum<dummy_function, dummy_function> sum_node;
}
```

This compiles and is a reasonable canary in the coal mine, but of course the concept is not actually correct. Is there a way to express this concept properly?

I have a hunch that it might not be because the set of concrete compileable expressions I'm trying to test for is infinite, so my follow-up question is: If this is in fact impossible, what would be the proper thing to do instead? Right now I have all relevant classes inherit a tag type and test for that, so the developer of a new expression type has to explicitly mark his type as compatible. This is again serviceable but not exactly pretty.

Comment: afaik you cannot know if something is "truly variadic". You would have to check all number of arguments to be sure. Eg it could be variadic, but passing 1001 arguments is not allowed. Isnt it sufficient to check for what you are actually calling?

Comment: In the library code I don't yet know the number of arguments; that's something the caller ultimately decides. Each concrete function has a requirement for the minmal number of arguments but none for the maximal: for example, the sum `x + y` needs to be evaluated with two arguments, and I just forward the same value vector to the subfunctions `x` and `y`. `x` only needs a 1-vector, but if given a 2-vector it'll just ignore the superfluous values.

Comment: somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/q/64738610/4117728

Answer (score 0):

Your concept needs to check that `f` is called with the correct number of variables. E.g. `2 * x + y` needs an `x` and `y`, not that `f` is callable with any number of arguments.

Let's add the requirement that a `mathy_function` have a member type `variables`.

```
template<typename T, int... Is>
double call(T t, std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
{
    return t(static_cast<double>(Is)...);
}

template<typename T>
concept mathy_function = requires(T f) {
  { T::variables::size() } -> std::same_as<std::size_t>
  call(f, std::make_integer_sequence<int, T::variables::size()>{});
  f(mathy_vector<T::variables::size()>{});
};
```

Now you also have something for `sum` to combine for it to specify the variables too.

```
template<mathy_function lhs, mathy_function rhs>
class sum { 
    using variables = decltype(boost::hana::union_(lhs::variables{}, rhs::variables{}));

    double operator()(mathy_vector<variables::size()> v) { ... };
    template <typename... Ts>
    double operator()(Ts... ts) { return *this(mathy_vector{ ts... }); }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. When I have `2 * x + y`, this consists of two subfunctions `2 * x` and `y`, both of which need to be callable with the same 2-valued vector; otherwise evaluation would incur a lot of input value copies. I thank you for your effort, and that's a good trick to remember. Still, in this case the idea is really to have arbitrary length.

Comment: @Wintermute you still want to know that it's `x` and `y` in that expression, and not e.g. `y` and `z`. So `mathy_vector<x, y, z>` converts to `mathy_vector<x, y>` (and these can all reference the same value objects)

Comment: I don't think I have an XY problem here, but I can provide some more specifics to make sure. The end goal is to say stuff like `auto g = f.diff(x, x, y);` for the partial derivative of `f` wrt x^2 and y. In many cases, `g` will lose dependencies on input vars, but the caller still wants to call `g` with the same inputs as `f`. The variables `x, y` are instances of types `variable<0>`, `variable<1>` and so forth, where the number corresponds to their place in the argument list, and what I called `mathy_vector` here is in the actual code `Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1>`.

Comment: @Wintermute that's what I'm describing. I'm just saying in the subexpression `2 * x`, you've not got any `y` term

Comment: I'm not sure In understand your point. `2 * x` still needs to be callable with x, y, and any number of other parameters that may have been required three layers of derivation ago, so the concept of a mathy_function in this context still requires operator() with a value vector of arbitrary length / argument pack of arbitrary length, no?.

Comment: @Wintermute no, each layer passes down only those values that are needed